# force bootstrap twitter nav dropdown to be 100% height of window

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to over write the built in Bootstarp style on navbar dropdowns to  no avail. I have some javascript trying to force it but I cant seem to get this to work. The native bootstrap javascript overwrites mine and it snaps back to being 228px height. Here is my code:

```
    // CLOSE NAV BARS NO OVERLAPPING
$('.navbar button').click(function(){ 
    var $target = $($(this).data('target')); 
    if(!$target.hasClass('in')){
        $('.navbar .in').removeClass('in').height(0);
    }
});

    //DROPDOWN MODE SELECTOR LOGIN
    // Force 100% height mobile navigation
    $('#navbar-collapse-1, #navbar-collapse-2').css('height', $(window).height());

    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
      var selText = $(this).text();
      $(this).parents('.modeSelector').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="modeSelect menu_toggleable glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span>');
    });

    $('#myMode-glyphicon-mobile, #myMode-glyphicon').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $(".modeSelect").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
    });

    $('#myMode-glyphicon-mobile, #myMode-glyphicon').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $(".modeSelect").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
    });

// FLIP ALL THE GLYPHICONS NAVBAR

   $('#navbar-collapse-1').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(this).addClass("dropdown-open").removeClass("dropdown-closed");
       if( $('#navbar-collapse-2').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){
          $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
          $(".myLogin-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
          $("#navbar-collapse-2").removeClass("dropdown-open");
          $("#navbar-collapse-2").addClass("dropdown-closed");
       }
    });

    $('#navbar-collapse-1').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(".myMenu-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(this).removeClass("dropdown-open").addClass("dropdown-closed");
    });


   $('#navbar-collapse-2').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(this).addClass("dropdown-open").removeClass("dropdown-closed");
       if( $('#navbar-collapse-1').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){
          $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
          $(".myMenu-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
          $("#navbar-collapse-1").removeClass("dropdown-open");
          $("#navbar-collapse-1").addClass("dropdown-closed");
       }
    });

    $('#navbar-collapse-2').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
       $(".myLogin-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       $(this).removeClass("dropdown-open").addClass("dropdown-closed");
       if( $('#navbar-collapse-1').hasClass('dropdown-open') ){
          $(".myMenu-glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-menu-up");
          $(".myMenu-glyphicon").addClass("glyphicon-menu-down");
       }
    });
```

HTML

```
    <div class="header">
<!-- BEGIN SEARCH AND LOGIN -->
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-4 logo hidden-xs"><a href="/"><img class="img-responsive" title="TMC Logo" src="images/tmcLogo.png" alt=""></a></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 login-wrapper hidden-xs">
                <ul class="list-inline header-list">
                    <li>Login to Navisphere</li> 
                      <li id="myMode-glyphicon" class="pull-right list-unstyled dropdown modeSelector">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Shippers <span class="modeSelect glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></a>
                        <ul class="modes list-unstyled dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Navisphere</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">CHRWTrucks</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">CHREUTransport</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  <form class="login-form" role="login">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="user-input form-control" placeholder="Username">
                      <input type="text" class="pass-input form-control" placeholder="Password">
                      <button type="submit" title="Login" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 search-wrapper hidden-xs">
                  <form class="search-form" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="search-input form-control" placeholder="Search">
                      <button type="submit" title="Search TMC" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
</div>
<div class="row mobileNav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand hidden-md hidden-xl hidden-sm hidden-lg" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" title="TMC Logo" src="images/tmcLogo.png" alt=""></a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" id="autocollapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="menu-toggle-text">MENU <i class="myMenu-glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
                    <span class="menu-toggle-text">LOGIN <i class="myLogin-glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></i></span>
                </button>
            </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dropdown-closed" id="navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <form class="search-form mobileSearch-form hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-xl hidden-lg" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="search-input form-control" placeholder="Search">
            <button type="submit" title="Search TMC" class="btn btn-default mobileSearch-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <li class="active dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICES <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu hover-dropdown hidden-xs mainDropdown">
        <div class="dividerNav"></div>
            <ul class="list-inline hidden-xs">
              <li><a href="#">TMS Technology</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Process Management</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Consulting</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Small Business Technology</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Global Control Tower</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>       
      </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">RESULTS</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu hover-dropdown hidden-xs mainDropdown">
        <div class="dividerNav"></div>
            <ul class="list-inline hidden-xs">
              <li><a href="#">Manufacturing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Automotive</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Produce</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Retail</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Paper/Packaging</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Beverage</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>       
      </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">RESOURCES</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu hover-dropdown hidden-xs mainDropdown">
        <div class="dividerNav"></div>
            <ul class="list-inline hidden-xs">
              <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">White Papers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Case Studies</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>       
      </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">ABOUT</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu hover-dropdown hidden-xs mainDropdown">
        <div class="dividerNav"></div>
            <ul class="list-inline hidden-xs">
              <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Values</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Leadership</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Charitble Giving</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>       
      </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">CONTACT</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu hover-dropdown hidden-xs mainDropdown">
        <div class="dividerNav"></div>
            <ul class="list-inline hidden-xs">
              <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Connect with an Expert</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Email News</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Update Preferences</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>       
      </li>
      </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dropdown-closed" id="navbar-collapse-2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-md hidden-xl hidden-sm hidden-lg mobileLogin">
            <li>
              <ul class="header-list list-unstyled">
                <li class="list-unstyled mobile">Login to Navisphere</li> 
                  <li id="myMode-glyphicon-mobile" class="list-unstyled dropdown modeSelector">
                    <a  href="#" class="mobileDropdown dropdown-toggle mobile" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Shippers <span class="modeSelect glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span></a>
                    <ul class="mobileList list-unstyled dropdown-menu mobile" role="menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Navisphere</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">CHRWTrucks</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">CHREUTransport</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <form class="login-form" role="login">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="user-input form-control longin-control" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="text" class="pass-input form-control login-control" placeholder="Password">
                <button type="submit" title="Login" class="btn btn-default mobileSearch-btn pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></i></button>
              </div>
            </form>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.container -->


</nav>  
</div>
</div>
<!-- END HEADER -->
```

CSS

```
CSS

/************* BASIC STYLES **************/
a {
    color:@tmcLightblue;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    }
p {
    margin: 10px 0;
    }
body{
    font-family:"Lato";
    overflow-x:hidden;
    }
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    }

/*********  NAV STYLES  *********/
.dividerNav{
    height:4px;
    background-color:#fff;
    }
.navbar.navbar-default > .container{
    border-bottom:1px solid @tmcDarkblue
    }
.menu-toggle-text{
    color:#4fb4e1;
    }
.navbar-toggle{
    border:none;
    padding:9px 1px;
    }
.navbar-toggle:hover .navbar-toggle:focus{
    background-color:none;
    }
.hover-dropdown{
    background-color:transparent;
    }
.hover-dropdown ul{
    border: medium none;
    border-radius:0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,58,99,0.80);
    padding: 25px 0;
    }
.navbar .hover-dropdown li a{
    color:#fff;
    margin: 0 18px;
    }
.header-list{
    margin-bottom:4px; 
    margin-top:15px;
    }
.navbar-brand{
    text-indent:-999px; 
    max-width:234px; 
    width:100%; 
    height:auto;
    }
.nav > li {
    display: block;
    position: static; 
    margin: 0 25px 0 0;
    }
.subscribe-input, .form-control:focus{
    box-shadow:none; 
    border-color:@tmcDarkblue;
    }
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
.navbar {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom:8px; 
    border-bottom:none; 
    border-top:0px; 
    border-radius:0px; 
    border-left:0px; 
    border-right:0px; 
    border-top:0px;
    }
.mobileNav{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    }   
.modeSelector{
    right:57px;
    }
.dropdown a{
    text-decoration:none;
    }
.navbar .hover-dropdown li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:@tmcLightblue;
    }
.dropdown-menu{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:none;
    border:none;
    border-radius:0;
    }
.mainDropdown{
    margin-top:-1px !important;
    }
.modes{
    border:1px solid @tmcDarkblue;
    border-radius:0px; 
    text-align:left;
    }
.modes li a{
    color:@tmcDarkblue;
    }
.modes li a:hover{
    color:@tmcLightblue;
    }
.user-input, .pass-input{
    width:41.5%;
    float:left;
    }
.search-input{
    width:82%;
    }
.subscribe-input, .form-control{
    border-radius:0px;
    border-color:@tmcDarkblue;
    color:@tmcDarkgrey;
    float:left;
    margin-right:4px;
    }
.glyphicon-arrow-right{
    color:#c05d1a;
    }
.glyphicon-search{
    color:#c05d1a;
    }
.logo, .search-wrapper {
    padding-top:39px
    }

#navbar-collapse-2, #navbar-collapse-1{
    position: static; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 2147483647;
    }
.nav > li.dropdown{
    /*border-bottom:2px solid #fff;*/
    }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus{
    color:@tmcLightblue;
    background-color:none; 
    background:none; 
    border-bottom:2px solid @tmcDarkblue;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent; 
    color:@tmcLightblue;
    }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent !important; 
    color: @tmcLightblue;
    }
.navbar-nav > li > a{
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
    }
.btn-default:hover, .btn-default:focus, .btn-default.focus, .btn-default:active, .btn-default.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    background-color: #fff; 
    border-color: @tmcOrange; 
    color: #fff;
    }
.glyphicon .glyphicon-search:hover {
    color: #fff;
    }

    /********* HEADLINES *********/
.headlineBorder{
    display:inline; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-size:20px;
    /*border-bottom:3px solid @tmcGreen;*/
    }
.headlineBorderblue{
    display:inline; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    /*border-bottom:3px solid @tmcDarkblue;*/
    }
.headlineBorderwhite{
    display:inline; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    /*border-bottom:3px solid #fff;*/
    color:#fff;
    }
.headlineBorderwhite_small {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    }
.headlineList{
    margin-bottom:15px;
    }
.btn-blue{
    border-color:@tmcLightblue;
    }
.btn-blue:hover, .btn-blue:active, .btn-blue:focus{
    background-color:@tmcDarkblue; 
    border-color:#fff;
    }
.glyphicon-menu-right:hover{
    color:#fff !important;
    }
.headlineGlyph:hover{
    color:@tmcLightblue !important;
    }
.btn-mobile-right {
    border:none;
    }
.btn-mobile-right:hover, .btn-mobile-right:focus, .btn-mobile-right.focus, .btn-mobile-right:active, .btn-mobile-right.active, .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    }
.glyphicon-menu-right, .glyphicon-menu-left{
    /*color:@tmcLightblue;*/
    }
.glyphicon-menu-right:hover, .glyphicon-menu-left:hover{
    color:#fff;
    }

.fourXfour{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
/********** SIDEBAR STYLES ***********/
.sidebarImg{
    margin:15px;
    }
.sidebarImg > a {
    display: block;
    }
.caption{
    margin-top:30px; 
    padding-left:15px; 
    padding-right:15px;
    }
.caption > h4{
    font-weight:bold; 
    line-height:12px;
    }

/*********** CONTACT PAGE STYLES ***********/
.pageIntroheadline > ul.contactList li a{
    color:#fff;
    }
.fourXfour > ul.contactList li a{
    color:@tmcLightblue;
    }
.contactList{
    margin-top:15px;
    }
#myMap{
    background:url('../images/worldMap.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 66.64%; /* (img-height / img-width * width) */
    /* (853 / 1280 * 100) */
    }

.mapDescriptionwrapper{
    display:block; 
    margin:-5px 0 0; 
    z-index:1;
    }
.mapTitle{
    background:@tmcLightblue; 
    padding:5px 8px; 
    border:1px solid #fff; 
    display:inline-block; 
    width:auto; 
    text-align:center; 
    color:#fff;
     z-index:10; 
     }
.mapTitle:hover{
    display:block; 
    background:orange; 
    display:inline-block;
    }
.mapDescription{
    display:none;
    }

#description-box{
   background-color: @tmcLightblue;
   border: 1px solid white;
    }


/********* INSIDE PAGE HERO IMAGE ************/

.insidePagehero {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-height: 232px;
    min-width: 392px;
    width: 100%;

}
.halfHero{
    padding:0;
    }
.insideHerocolorPicker-orange{
    background:@tmcOrange;
    }
.insideHerocolorPicker-darkBlue{
    background:@tmcDarkblue;
    }
.insideHerocolorPicker-lightBlue{
    background:@tmcLightblue;
    }
.insideHerocolorPicker-green{
    background:@tmcGreen;
    }
.pageIntroheadline{
    display: block;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top:5%;
    margin-bottom:0;
    }
.pageHero {
    padding:0 15px 0 0;
    }
/*********  HOMEPAGE MARKETING AREA  *********/
.marketing-wrapper{
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    }
.mareting-section{
    padding:0;
    }
/************************* FLIPPING STYLES *******************/

.marketing-wrapper h2{
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }
.flipperWrap{
    padding:0;
    }
.card {
  width:100%;
  max-width: 750.666px;
  height: 348px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear:both;
  }
 .flip {
    width:100%;
    max-width: 750.666px;
    height: 396px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    clear:both;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    }
.front, .back {
  padding: 0px;
  }
.front {
  background-color: transparent;
  }
.back {
  background-color: transparent;
  }
.arrowFront{
   height:230px !important; 
  }
.arrowBack{
   height:230px !important;
   background:#c05d1a url(../images/triangle.jpg) no-repeat bottom right;     
  }

.blogInside, .tmsInside, .globalInside{
    height: 50%;
    margin: 2.5% auto;
    width: 78%;
    }

.flipBack{
    color:#fff; 
    padding: 0px;
    }
.flipOrange{
    background-color:@tmcOrange; 
    }
.flipDarkblue{
    background-color:@tmcDarkblue; 
    }
.flipLightblue{
    background-color:@tmcLightblue; 
    }
.flipGreen{
    background-color:@tmcGreen; 
    }
.flipDarkgrey{
    background-color:@tmcDarkgrey; 
    }
.flipLightgrey{
    background-color:@tmcLightgrey; 
    }
.blogIcon{
    background:url("../images/blogIcon.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 38px; 
    width: 46px; 
    float:left; 
    margin:0 22px 0 0;
    }
.tmsIcon{
    background:url('../images/tmsIcon.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 38px; 
    width: 46px; 
    float:left; 
    margin:0 22px 0 0;
    }
.globalIcon{
    background:url('../images/globalIcon.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 38px; 
    width: 38px; 
    float:left; 
    margin:0 22px 0 0;
    }

/**************** LEADERSHIP SLIDER STYLES *****************/
.leadershipSlider{
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    }
.leadershipCol {
    float: left;
    margin-right:15px;
    }
.leadershipName, .slider{
    color:#fff; 
    height:auto; 
    width:82%;
    max-width:138px;
    background-color:@tmcOrange; 
    padding:10px; 
    margin:-85px 0 0 38%; 
    border:1px solid #fff; 
    display:block; 
    float:left;
    }
.leadershipName .glyphicon.glyphicon-menu-right.pull-right{
    color:#fff; 
    margin:-8px 0;
    }
.leadershipImg{
    display:block; 
    float:left
    }

/**************** Client Results Page *******************/
.introText{
    padding:0;
    }
.clientResultsGrid{
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    }
.panel-default{
    padding:0;
    border:none;
    }
.panel-default > .panel-heading{
    border:none;
    color:@tmcDarkblue;
    background:#fff;
    }
.panel{
    box-shadow:none;
    }
.panel-body{
    background:@tmcLightgrey;
    padding: 15px 0;
    }
.panelResults{
    margin-bottom:15px;
    }
.panel-heading{
    padding: 0;
    background:@tmcLightblue;
    border-radius:0px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    }
.panel-title{
    color:#fff;
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
.accordionResults{
    padding: 0;
    }
.accordionIcon{
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 33px;
    min-width: 50px;
    padding: 7.5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    }
.resultsIcon{
    padding: 0 0.5%;
    width:auto;
    border-right:2px solid #fff;       
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    }
.resultsTitle{}
.glyphBox{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #c0c920;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 15px 0 25px;
    min-height: 32px;
    min-width: 42px;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
a.glyphBox:hover, a.glyphBox:focus{
    color:@tmcGreen; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    outline:nonne; 
    outline-offset:0px;
    }
.glyphBox .indicator{
    color:#fff; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
.preResultsaccordion {
    padding:0;
    }
.preResultsaccordion > .inside{
    padding:0; 
    margin:15px 0;
    }
#collapseOne, #collapseTwo, #collapseThree, #collapseFour{
    padding:0;
    }

@media (max-width:@screen-lg) {

}
@media (max-width:@screen-md) {
        .navbar-nav > li > a {
        border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
        }
    .modeSelector{
        right:0px;
        }
    .search-input{
        width:78%;
        }
    .user-input, .pass-input{
        width:37%;
        }

    }
@media (max-width:@screen-sm) {

    /*FEEDSLIDER*/ 
    .headlineWrapper, .headlineWrapper-green, .headlineWrapper-white{
        width:80%;
        }
    .mobile{
        color:#fff;
        } 
    .headlineHero{
        font-size:medium;
        }
    .secondaryNavigation-wrapper{
        background:@tmcDarkblue;
        padding: 15px 0 0;
        }
    .secondaryNavigation-mobile{
        color:#fff;
        list-style:none;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        padding-left:0;
        padding-right:0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:47%;

        }
    .secondaryNavigation-mobile a{
        color:#fff;
        }
    .secondaryNavigation-mobile a:hover{
        color:@tmcLightblue;
        }
    ul.secondaryNavigation-mobile li{
        list-style:none;
        width:47%;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        margin-right:3px;
        padding-bottom:0;
        padding-left:0;
        padding-right:0;
        vertical-align: top;
        padding-bottom:15px;
        }
    .navbar-toggle{
        font-size:medium;
        }

    .navbar-collapse{
        background-color: rgba(0,58,99,0.80);
        }
    .navbar-nav{
        margin:15px -15px;
        } 
    .nav > li > a{
        text-align:left; 
        padding-left:0px; 
        padding-right:0px; 
        color:#fff !important;
        } 
    .nav > li > a:hover{
        color:@tmcLightblue !important;
        } 
    .nav > li{
        margin:0px;
        }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus{
        border-bottom:0px solid transparent;
         color:@tmcLightblue !important;
        }
    .navbar-brand{
        max-width:125px;
        margin:0 0 0 5px;
        } 
    #navbar-collapse-2, #navbar-collapse-1{
        position: absolute; 
        width: 100%; 
        z-index: 2147483647;
        }
    .subscribe-input{
        border-radius:0px; 
        border-color:@tmcDarkblue; 
        color:@tmcDarkgrey; 
        float:left; 
        margin-right:4px;
        } 
    .search-form{
        background-color:transparent !important; 
        color:#fff;
        }
    .mobileSearch-btn{
        border-color: #fff; 
        background-color:transparent;
        } 
    .mobileSearch-btn:hover{
        border-color: #fff; 
        background-color:transparent;
        } 
    .glyphicon-search {
        color: #fff;
        } 
    .glyphicon-arrow-right{
        color: #fff;
        }
    .mobileLogin{
        text-align:left;
        } 
    .login-control{
        float:none;
        }
    .user-input, .pass-input{
        margin:0 0 5px 0;
        width:100%; 
        float:none;
        } 
    .dropdown-menu{
        text-align:left;
        } 
    .mobileDropdown{
        background-color: transparent !important; 
        border: 1px solid #fff !important; 
        color: #fff; 
        margin: 5px 0 0; 
        padding: 6px 13px; 
        display: block;
        } 
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        background-color: #fff; 
        padding: 5px 0;
        } 
    .mobileList{ 
        background-color: #fff !important;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 0;
    } 
    .navbar-nav .open .mobileList{
        position:absolute; 
        width:100%;
        } 
    .mobileList li{
        padding:4px 14px; 
        border-bottom:1px solid @tmcDarkblue;
        }
    .mobileNav{
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        }
```

}

Comment: get rid of the JS code and overwrite the CSS. Do you have chrome?

Comment: is the bootstrap being controlled by the css? I do have chrome.

Comment: Why will chrome help? I am using firebug with firefox but I can use either one.

Comment: With chrome you can edit the CSS straight in the browser and it will re-render on the page without having to make changes to CSS document and refresh

Comment: I can do this with Firefox but the issue I am seeing is that bootstrap some how is over writing it and making up the height somehow. My javascript works but then it snaps to 280px which is getting in there via javascript of some bootstrap file.

Comment: I am now using this line of css to force the height but the animation opening and closing is very glitch. I wish I had more time to get this right. I don't like bootstrap very much, I feel locked into only a few options.

.navbar-collapse.collapse.in.dropdown-open{
 height:220vh;
 }

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `.dropdown-menu`  and `.sub-menu` classes.

To change the height of the menu try this:

```
.dropdown-menu
{
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: That did not work. I also tried to put height:100% on the #navbar-collapse-1, #navbar-collapse-2 but it made it worse and showed a scroll bar and hid most of the content in the dropdown.

Comment: In chrome right-click on your drop down menu, and select 'Inspect element' it should reveal the CSS. you should see something in regard to height or max-height. (On the element class '.dropdown-menu')

Comment: I do not think I am using the .dropdown-menu

These are the classes I am using:

When closed
collapse navbar-collapse dropdown-closed

When open
navbar-collapse collapse in dropdown-open

I also see a class is added and before it closes or opens there is a class named collapsing

Comment: Okay, so in chrome you should be able to edit the CSS values when you select 'inspect element', Try changing the values, or adding max-height or height values.

Comment: when I add 220vmax it works but isn't exactly what I want since the open and close is very glitch. Hmmm I may have to just by pass bootstrap at this point.

Comment: Well, I can tell you if you fiddle with the CSS enough you can get it. It's just kind of a pain the first few times.

Comment: I will keep trying. I tried to create a bootply but its not reading my css or javascript correctly.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be much more help.

Comment: Its ok Jordan I really appreciate the effort. I am going to try and build this bootply and edit my question or answer it if I can. I know I ready a lot of the similar cases on here but the html, body {height:100%;} Didn't work like it did for those other cases.